# Acessar arquivo javascript localmente em Xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin-forms

estou com uma duvida de como acessar um arquivo .js na minha aplicação 
mobile(Andriod)usando o xamarin forms,como abaixo :

```
var htmlSource = new HtmlWebViewSource();

htmlSource.Html =
           @"<html>
                <head>
                    <script type='text/javascript'>

                     function LaunchSCO(organizationItemID,href) {
                        alert(""Ola"");
                        windows.API = new teste();
                    }
                    </script>
                  </head>
                  <body>
                        <a href=""javascript:LaunchSCO('4020','');"" style='text-decoration:none;'>Abrir cursoooooS</a>
                        <div id='divCurso'>

                        </div>
                  <--Aqui é o arquivo que eu quero abrir localmente-->
                  <script src=""js/teste.js""></script>
                  </body>
            </html>";

WebView1.Source = htmlSource;
```

Minha dificuldade é aonde devo guarda esse arquivo e como faço para acessar ele quando eu gerar minha APK.

Obs:procurei por File in Xamarin porem não encontrei uma forma pratica de guarda e ler arquivo js.

Comment: O xamarin não executa javascript. O componente `WebView` é que o faz. você precisa ter uma página já definida no webview que contenha esse javascript e emular a partir dela.

Comment: Ou então executar com o Eval. `WebView1.Eval(/* Chamar função javascript da página*/);`